# SyncFolderItems - syncState size becomes huge! what can I do?

Tags: objective-c, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I am writing a mobile mail application and I am using the SyncFolderItems request to sync my folder.
The problem is, that when dealing with folders with a lot of items (e.g. 12000) the syncState becomes huge, and obviously this is not good for a mobile device..
Is there a workaround to this? Should I abandon the Sync operation and use pull subscriptions instead (And perhaps use findItem operation to get the initial id's? )
Thanks!!

Comment: your question is more a design question that a coding one. And its a bit vague. Youre asking for a way to not have a huge sync state when the folder size is huge?

Comment: Yes,I am asking how to have a small sized syncState with a huge folder size.

Comment: The the answer would be to change your code logic. I cant give you a direct answer.

Answer (score 0):

What other people say, its a design question.
If you have a lot of e-mail, howmuch do you really need?
I mean, do i need 12000 items on my phone, i dont think so.
Good option is, save all the item id's with subject or something.
When click on the item, get the other properties. And don't save the information, it can be called from the Exchange Server...